# Wrap node inside xslt element based on condition

Tags: xslt

I have to wrap certain nodes inside another element conditionally. In the below example I need to wrap CityName inside MyCity if city is Venezia. I have achieved it now, but i think there is better way of writing this without repeating the  node. One way is to create a template and call that for the CityName, but is there any more elegant ways with fewer lines of code?

Input

```
<cities>
    <city name="Milano"/>
    <city name="Paris"/>
    <city name="Munchen"/>
    <city name="Lyon"/>
    <city name="Venezia"/>
</cities>
```

My Xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="city">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name='Venezia'">
                <myCity>
                    <CityName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </CityName>
                </myCity>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <CityName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </CityName>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Identity Transform-->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I am looking for

```
<cities>
    <CityName>Milano</CityName>
    <CityName>Paris</CityName>
    <CityName>Munchen</CityName>
    <CityName>Lyon</CityName>
    <myCity>
        <CityName>Venezia</CityName>
    </myCity>
</cities>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that all you need is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="city[@name='Venezia']">
        <myCity>
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </myCity>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="city">
        <CityName>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </CityName>
    </xsl:template>
    
   <!-- Identity Transform-->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3 it boils down to

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="city[@name]">
    <CityName>{@name}</CityName>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="city[@name = 'Venezia']">
    <myCity>
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </myCity>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" on-multiple-match="use-last"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`xsl:next-match` is also available in XSLT 2.0 but you would need to specify priority on a template instead of relying on `xsl:mode on-multiple-match="use-last"`. Text value templates in XSLT 3 are just syntactic sugar that can be replace with `xsl:value-of`.